# SSRS Delivery to SharePoint without Integration

Tags: ssrs-2008, wss-3.0

I need to deliever an SSRS report via subscription to a SharePoint document library.  Setting it up in integrated mode is not an option.

I have tried to use WebDAV interface to SharePoint, but for some unknown reason, I'm getting an access denied.  I attempted to run the SSRS Service as a network user which has access to the SharePoint server.

Any help with figuring out the WebDAV solution or an alternative would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using SharePoint Object Model or services?

http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2009/04/18/how-to-upload-a-filedocument-using-the-sharepoint-object-model.aspx

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article712-how-to-upload-file-to-sharepoint-document-library-with-object-model-.aspx

Comment: I have found a way to upload the file directly via code using some code found at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rohitpuri/archive/2007/04/10/upload-download-file-to-from-wss-document-library-using-dav.aspx

Comment: The only downside to that, is it makes it a 2 step process to publish the doc.. If the UNC path worked, there would be no need for an intermediate step.